# Refresh rate slows to 1 FPS/ unusable when I close the lid on my laptop Dell Precision 7530 and use external monitors after upgrade to Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: nvidia, graphics, display, lid, framerate

After upgrade from Linux Ubuntu 20.10 to Ubuntu 21.04 on a Dell Precision 7530, with Nvidia drivers correctly installed and reporting correctly using recommended nvidia-driver-470. With a laptop lid open, and run `glxgears` from terminal, refresh rate is 60-62 FPS.

With laptop lid closed FPS drops immediately to 1 FPS and is unusable. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: I have the same problem if I use X11 instead of Wayland on one of my optimus laptops. The other optimus laptop I use doesn't have this problem. I've read somewhere that it's like this because of way how your GPUs are connected and in my opinion the cause of the problem could be regression in X11 update but I am not an expert. Did you try switching to Wayland and checking if the problem is still there? In my case the problem was gone.

Comment: Thanks, I upgraded to Ubuntu 21.10 and problem vanished, not really a fix to the issue but did avoid it!

Comment: @LeighMathieson so updating to 21.10 fixed it? or moving to wayland did?

Comment: @Dima updating to 21.10 fixed it for me